# Do calculations with static/global const primitives occur in compile time?

Tags: c++

```
const int thing = 1234;

int func( int hello )
{
    return hello / (thing*123+321);
}
```

**Is** `(thing*123+321)` **computed in compile time?**

If `thing` was a user defined type with `int operator*` would it also happen in compile time?

If `thing` was a float or double would it also happen in compile time?

If I forcibly change `thing` in runtime would `(thing*123+321)` be unchanged?

Comment: You can get the answer on your own if you have a look into the generated code!

Comment: @hansmaad I needed to know the answer for more than what my particular compiler happens to do.

Comment: The generated code is binary (or assembly, if one specifies the appropriate compiler options).  It wouldn't help someone who doesn't know assembly language.

Comment: If you "forcibly change `thing`" then you have invoked undefined behavior (by modifying a `const` object). The standard doesn't care whether the program keeps `(thing*123+321)` unchanged, starts using a new value, crashes, or does the thing with the demons and the nose. If you want to know what a particular implementation actually does, you could try it or you could look at a disassembly of the code it emits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no guarantee that it will be, but any optimizing compiler will precompute this value. It will probably turn that division operation into a multiplication by a precomputed reciprocal value too.

Comment: I believe the reciprocal value can only be used if an option equivalent to `-ffast-math` (in GCC) is specified since this code may yield subtly different results from multiplication.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: For *integer* math?

Comment: A caveat to the caveat -- as you say it's not guaranteed that the value will be computed at compile-time, but it is guaranteed that the compiler is *capable* of computing it, since it's an integer constant expression, and it could be used as the size of an array, a template parameter, etc, in which case it *would* be guaranteed computed at compile time. Basically a compiler would have to be carefully avoiding all possible optimizations in order to not compute it at compile time :-)

Answer (score 1):

In general, **constant expressions** can and usually will be computed at compile time. Since you can and if you do use constant expressions as template arguments, there's actually no way around that.

The big question is now what constitutes a constant expression. In C++98/03, your `thing` would qualify as one, but a constant function of `thing` would not, since there's no way to tell the compiler that a function is "pure" in that sense.

Some compilers offer extensions (such as GCC's *attributes* "pure" and "const"), but that's outside the scope of the language. C++11 introduces the explicit `constexpr` keyword, which allows you to declare all sorts of expressions as constant and thus eligible for compile-time evaluation. (For instance, GCC is built with the GMP and MPFR libraries in order to perform those compile-time computations to any degree of precision, so as to be able to target any platform.)

Answer (score 0):

> Is (thing*123+321) computed in compile time?

Yes.

> hello / (thing*123+321);

In this case, the full expression is computed at runtime. since the argument in your function `hello` is unknown at until you run the program.

Comment: The argument isn’t used in the expression. Nothing (except rules of floating-point accuracy, but in this particular case not even that) forbids the compiler from calculating the sub-expression at compile-time.

Comment: The `thing*123+321` part *can be* calculated at compile time, as all its values are known at that point.

Comment: The wording is a bit misleading here. "Full expression" is a specific C++ term (§1.9/10), and refers to expressions that are not sub-expressions. In this case, the full expression is a division expression, and indeed the division expression is computed at runtime.